# Why saved by batching 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have identical character models, I look at the Debug Frame, the rendering is completely different Draw Calls. If the models are absolutely identical, but he draws them separately. Dynamic batching checkbox enabled in Project Settings. Also on the material there is a tick Enable GPU instancing [image]
[Object in inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B04bN.png)
[Material on objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gDLw.png)

I looked in the Frame Debug, in the end I didn’t come to any conclusion, since in fact it should compose objects into one

Comment: All Draw Mesh are the same objects that are in the Frame Debug screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Remove the SkinnedMeshRenderer Component from the mesh on the object. And install MeshFilters, MeshRenderer. Unfortunately, for unknown reasons, SkinnedMeshRenderer is not a batch